# Hello I'm in 10th grade and I was trying out different HTML questions. I'm struggling with html output

Tags: html

Need help with this:

[image]

So far with my current knowledge, I was able to design till here but it looks wrong and something is missing.

**My code -**

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border=2cellspacing=4cellpadding=4 border color dark="red" border color light="blue"
    align="center">
    <caption>List of Books</caption>
    <tr>
    <th row span=2align="center">ItemNo</th>
    <th row span=2align="center">ItemName</th>
    <th align="center"colspan=2>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th align="center">Rs.</th>
    <th align="center">Paise</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What looks wrong and what is missing ?

Comment: @sanojlawrence the table on snippet is different from the one shown by the picture in the question which he/she aimed for :) . I think that this is sort of school assignment

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you need to enclose the values for the attributes in doublequotes, no matter what it is (integer, string, functions, etc.) i.e.

```
<tr rowspan="3"></tr>
<span class="short"></span>
<button onclick="jump()"></button>
```

In the table, there's no such attribute called `row span` and `col span`. It's `rowspan` and `colspan`.

If you want to set the padding that's same across all cells in the table, you can simply add it to `<style>` and use CSS for it. If all cells have different styles, you can also apply the attribute `style` for each `th` and `td`.

```html
<style>
  td, th {
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">No.</th>
    <th colspan="2">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Rs.</th>
    <th>Paise</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <caption>List of Books</caption>
        <tr>
            <th style="padding: 10px" rowspan="2">ItemNo</th>
            <th style="padding: 10px" rowspan="2">ItemName</th>
            <th style="padding: 10px" colspan="2">Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px">Rs.</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">Paise</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px">1</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">Programming in Python</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">500</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px">2</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">Programming in Java 30</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">345</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px">00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).